# How to change HTML content if there's an active user session with Node.js/Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to remove the login/signup buttons after a user has logged on, but I can't seem to figure how. This is part of my header file which I want to change.

```
<section class="header">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <nav class="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/">Images</a></li>
                <li><a href="/albums">Albums</a></li>
                <li><a href="/tags">Tags</a></li>
                <li><a href="/upload">Upload</a></li>
            </ul>
            <button class="logIn">Log In</button>
            <button class="signUp">Sign Up</button>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

This is my login route which sets req.session.user_id to the id of the user.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var db = require('../helpers/db');
var Password = require("node-php-password");

router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var username = req.body.username;
  var password = req.body.password;

  db.query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?', [username], function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
    var userId = results[0].id;
    var hash = results[0].password;

    if(Password.verify(password, hash)){
      req.session.user_id = userId;
      res.redirect('/');
    }
  });



});

module.exports = router;
```

What I think must be done is to pass the req.session.user_id to the header file and but I'm not sure how. I use EJS as template engine.

Comment: this can't be done directly because you can not modify static html try using some view engine like ejs or handlebar

Comment: I am using EJS, however, I'm sure how to get the session inside the ejs file in order to use it in my if statement.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the EJS then:

1. Set renderer engine

   ```
   express.set('view engine', 'ejs');
   ```
2. Prepare your data for template eg.

   ```
   let isLoggedIn = [eval your value here]
   ```
3. Inside of post('/') route, right before the end of a block, render your template and pass required data

   ```
   res.render('pages/index', {
     isLoggedIn: isLoggedIn
   });
   ```
4. In your template add an if in appropriate place

   ```
   <%if (!isLoggedIn) { %>
     (...render button)
   <% } %>
   ```

Here is [a nice tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application) which can help you to understand how to pass data from a model to a view